# How can I limit the number of emails I want to search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'm using `nodejs` with the library `imap`, and I'm trying to only get the last email but i don't know the parameter exact to filter. Does anyone know? Thank you!

```
const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
            imap.once('ready', () => {
                imap.openBox('INBOX', false, () => {
                    imap.search(['ALL', ['SINCE', new Date()]], (err, results) => {
                        const f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '' });
```

Comment: Replace the `"ALL"`  with just `"*"` and it should work. `"ALL"` means `"1:*"`, which in turn means "all messages from number 1 to the last one, inclusive". I guess you might be able to drop the SINCE, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look like you can. But you can use `RECENT` instead of `ALL` and then in the callback just get the first item in the array

Comment: oh thats right ill get the first one in the callback, thanks!

Comment: `RECENT` is wrong; it'll return an empty list quite often.